# Unable to connect mysql from Sequel gem

Tags: mysql, ruby, sequel

When I try to connect to MySQL from Sequel. I am getting these errors:

```
require 'rubygems'
        require 'sequel'
        DB = Sequel.connect(:adapter => 'mysql', :user => 'root', :host => 'localhost', :database => 'scanty',:password=>'xx')
        DB.tables
    Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: NameError uninitialized constant Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:98:in `connect'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/database.rb:92:in `initialize'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:166:in `call'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:166:in `make_new'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:153:in `available'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:144:in `acquire'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:143:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:143:in `acquire'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/connection_pool.rb:105:in `hold'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/database.rb:471:in `synchronize'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:128:in `execute'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset.rb:314:in `execute'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:342:in `execute'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/mysql.rb:298:in `fetch_rows'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset.rb:185:in `each'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/convenience.rb:156:in `map'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/dataset/convenience.rb:156:in `map'
        from /opt/local/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/sequel-3.2.0/lib/sequel/adapters/shared/mysql.rb:60:in `tables'
        from (irb):6irb(main):007:0> Sequel::DatabaseConnectionError: NameErro
```

Comment: Seems that your error is truncated? Also, where is the host in your function call?

Comment: i added host but it still throwing same error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to install the native MySQL driver, the pure ruby one is not compatible with Sequel.

Depending on your Ruby installation, just doing `gem install mysql` may be enough.  However, if the pure Ruby mysql.rb file is already in your Ruby load path, you either need to remove it from the load path or use `gem('mysql')` before calling `Sequel.connect`.

Answer (score 1):

You are missing the `:host=>'localhost'` or whatever your host is.

Also, and this is just purely for performance reasons, you should try to enable `:compress`. It can save a TON of bandwidth.

http://sequel.rubyforge.org/rdoc/files/doc/opening_databases_rdoc.html

**Edit**: OK, if it's not the host, perhaps it's a conflict? See http://groups.google.com/group/sequel-talk/browse_thread/thread/ee39640a92351f1?pli=1. Also http://www.mail-archive.com/sequel-talk@googlegroups.com/msg02275.html

Comment: thanks,

I have two versions of mysql gem installed on machine.