# Sequel gem & MySQL (Ruby + Windows): load mysql.so file, not mysql.rb

Tags: mysql, ruby, windows, rubygems, sequel

Using ruby gem 'sequel', when I attempt `Sequel.connect("mysql://localhost")`, I get the following error:

```
Sequel::AdapterNotFound: LoadError: require 'mysql' did not define Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS!
  You are probably using the pure ruby mysql.rb driver,
  which Sequel does not support. You need to install
  the C based adapter, and make sure that the mysql.so
  file is loaded instead of the mysql.rb file.
```

How can I get this gem to connect to a MySQL server?

**Sys**: Win XP, Ruby 1.8.7, Mysql 5.1.51

Comment: I have found the recommendation to run something along the following lines in multiple places:
`sudo env ARCHFLAGS="-arch x86_64" gem install ruby-mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config`

However, I'm running Windows, so I tried `gem install ruby-mysql -- --with-mysql-config="C:\Program Files\...\my.ini"`  (I don't know that my.ini is my config file.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution on this thread: [Unable to connect mysql from Sequel gem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1144610/unable-to-connect-mysql-from-sequel-gem)

Call `gem('mysql')` to specify use of the native sql driver before `Sequel.connect()`.

(Upvotes for Jeremy Evans)

Answer (score 1):

Sequel is an ORM on top of existing Database adapters.

The error you're receiving is because `mysql` gem has not been installed.

You should be able to solve this problem doing `gem install mysql`

Since MySQL gem on Windows is provided as binaries, it is very sensible in relation to the dependency of `libmysql.dll` available in your system.

I recommend you the following tutorial I put together to cover the proper installation of the gem against modern versions of MySQL:

http://blog.mmediasys.com/2011/07/07/installing-mysql-on-windows-7-x64-and-using-ruby-with-it/

Hope this helps.

Comment: So now I've carried out the instructions you provided, but when I try to use Sequel, I get the same error I listed up top.

Comment: So did you install the mysql gem? does it work from IRB like the article I linked? What does `puts Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS` output in the IRB console?

Comment: I did install the mysql gem, and I did succeed in using to connect to my local server. ... The command in your last comment returns `NameError: uninitialized constant Mysql::CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS`. ... I have not been able to use the mysql gem to connect to the remote server at work because of the following error: `Mysql::Error: Client does not support authentication protocol requested by server; consider upgrading MySQL client`, which is why I'm trying to get the sequel gem to work for a mysql connection.